# Why does my array not save or reload after quitting killing app. iOS Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, nsarray, save

Quitting my app and reloading seems to clear my array or I'm not reloading it properly. I can't see what I'm missing. webview loads and adds urltextfield to object pasturls in to array. Each time user starts typing something they already sent to webiew from textfield it displays in a tableview. Works great every time until the app is killed. Background return is fine. Please?

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
NSMutableArray *pastUrls;
NSMutableArray *autocompleteUrls;
UITableView *autocompleteTableView;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *autocompleteTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *pastUrls;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *autocompleteUrls;

- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController   

@synthesize pastUrls;
@synthesize autocompleteUrls;
@synthesize autocompleteTableView;


- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

if (![pastUrls containsObject:urlField.text]) {
    [pastUrls addObject:urlField.text];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:pastUrls forKey:@"PastUrls"];
    }

- (void)loadView {
pastUrls = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"PastUrls"] mutableCopy];
pastUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"PastUrls", nil];
[super loadView];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
autocompleteUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {

[autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
for(NSString *curString in pastUrls) {
    NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];
    if (substringRange.location == 0) {
        [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];  
    }
}
[autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section      {
return [autocompleteUrls count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

}
@end
```

Comment: Are you sure you can just save and retrieve `NSArray` objects to `NSUserDefaults` without *archiving* the contents?  I don't think you can.  Also your `loadView` implementation looks like nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is an issue with your pastUrls. In the loadView, you set two different contents in it :

```
- (void)loadView {
pastUrls = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"PastUrls"] mutableCopy];
pastUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"PastUrls", nil];
}
```

The second one should be removed. Moreover, there are some strange things in your implementation, like the loadView and viewDidLoad functions. More likely you should have :

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

if (![pastUrls containsObject:urlField.text]) {
    [pastUrls addObject:urlField.text];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:pastUrls forKey:@"PastUrls"];
    // You might need to synchronize your NSUserDefaults content
    // if so, uncomment the following line
    // [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}

// Used only if you do not use a XIB file to load the graphical interface
//- (void)loadView {
//}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; // Was missing in your current implementation
    autocompleteUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    pastUrls = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"PastUrls"] mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working. As it is now I have not needed to uncomment // [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; if that changes, I will update here. Thanks, again.

Comment: FYI, as pastUrls is set using the function 'mutableCopy', you'll need to release it in the dealloc function, or your class will leak.

Comment: I thought ARC was doing that for me. Is this not true? Obviosly autorelease won't work. How can I dealloc best? pastUrls = nil;?

Comment: I thought ARC was doing that for me. Is this not true? Obviosly autorelease won't work. How can I dealloc best? -(void)dealloc {
    pastUrls = nil;
    
}?

Comment: Ok sorry, if you are using ARC so no pb.

Comment: everything has suddenly stopped working with displaying the pastUrls data. The table will show but it contains no data. Nothing has changed as far as I can tell.

Comment: Mmmm, strange, may be there were an issue when storing the urls in the NSUserDefaults

Comment: I posted a new question with my new issue. If you get a chance to look at it I'd really be grateful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335307/tableview-just-suddenly-stopped-displaying-cell-data-nothing-changed-as-far-as